# performance issue while reading many files

Tags: java, performance, jvm, java-7

I am reading around 2000 text files using Files.readAllLines but it is consuming 100MB.

here is the code snippet

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
try {
    Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), charset);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JVM is taking 100MB+ for reading 2000 files. (I checked with JVisualVM )
Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: do you want all the files, or you can do the processing one by one. It depends upon your requirement. Choose wisely and select the appropiate method to read the files.

Comment: consider batch operations .

Comment: JVM may take more memory than actually required. You can tune that via JVM arguments like -Xmx.

Comment: 100MB is nothing.

Comment: You are concerned about less than $1 of memory.  Does that sound a lot to you?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have 1000 text files; and your code reads them all into memory. So, a lot of lists with strings are created.

If you don't want all that - why are you using a method that reads files into memory?

Or, to give a concrete answer: your code is fine (of course, assuming that your real code does have something like

```
List<String> allTheLines = Files...
```

as it wouldn't make too much sense to read all those files and dump their content to ... nowhere.

In that sense, there is really not much you can do here. Unless you decide that you actually do not want **all** lines in memory, then there interesting ways to do that, see here for some [Java8](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/3-ways-to-read-file-line-by-line-in.html) code.